# Can jquery mobile and bootstrap be combined in the same project

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

I like to combine Bootstrap and Jquery Mobile, Although i know what Bootstrap is, i have little knowledge About Jquery Mobile.

Can you please provide me with some detail about the difference of Bootstrap and JQuery mobile and also can these two frameworks be combined together in Project?.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery mobile, is a framework that focus on devices like mobile or tablet, although it work in large desktop, But the main advantage to use this, is to provide good user experience in mobile or tablet devices,
But bootstrap is a framework that is good for any screen, like tablet, mobile, desktop and...